# WAM book: How is code generated when dealing with argument registers (L1)?

Tags: prolog, warren-abstract-machine

I am working through Hassan Ait-Kaci's book [Warren's Abstract Machine - A Tutorial Reconstruction](http://wambook.sourceforge.net/). Currently I am stuck on section 2.4, "Argument Registers".

To be precise, what I don't understand is how to get from these register assignments (p.22) (for query `p(Z,h(Z,W),f(W))`):

```
A1 = Z
A2 = h(A1,X4)
A3 = f(X4)
X4 = W
```

to these instructions (p.24):

```
put_variable X4,A1
put_structure h/2,A2
set_value X4
set_variable X5
put_structure f/1,A3
set_value X5
call p/3
```

Like, where does X5 come from all of a sudden? In the register assignments, X4 refers to variable W, and there's no X5. But in the instructions, X5 refers to (what is/was essentially) W, and X4 now refers to Z. I am not seeing an explanation in the book. What am I missing?

Comment: In the printed edition, these are pages 17 and 19 (Figure 2.9), respectively.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to understand this but to no avail. Nothing in the [errata](http://wambook.sourceforge.net/). Here are some notes:

## Instruction review

- `put_structure f/n,Xi`: push a new `STR` (and adjoining functor) cell onto the heap and copy that cell into the allocated register address;
- `set_variable Xi`: push a new `REF` cell onto the heap containing its own address, and copy it into the given register;
- `set_value Xi`: push a new cell onto the heap and copy into the register's value.
- In case of query:

  - `put_variable Xn,Ai`: the first occurrence of a variable in i-th argument position pushes a new unbound `REF` cell onto the heap and copies it into that variable's register as well as argument register `Ai`; and
  - `put_value Xn,Ai` (used for query): a later occurrence copies its value into argument register `Ai`.
- In case of fact:

  - `get_variable Xn,Ai`: the first occurrence of a variable in i-th argument position sets it to the value of argument register `Ai`; and
  - `get_value Xn,Ai`: a later occurrence unifies with the value of `Ai`.

## So, about that query

```
p(Z,h(Z,W),f(W)))
```

It seems to be coded differently on pages 17 and 19

```
Page 17 in the print edition    Page 19 in the print edition
(given as is)                   (translated by me from the WAM code)

A1 = Z                          A1 = Z
A2 = h(A1,X4)                   A2 = h(X4,X5)
A3 = f(X4)                      A3 = f(X5)
X4 = W                          X4 = Z
                                X5 = W
```

**Edit**: It seems the code on the left allows variables appearing in non-root-positions to be in "argument registers" which is disallowed on the right, hence indirection.

## The code

The `Ai` are the argument registers, the `Xi` are some value registers.

```
put_variable X4,A1       Z is a argument root freshvar created in X4
                         and also goes into A1
put_structure h/2,A2     h/2 functor goes into A2
                         (1)
set_value X4             New (empty) cell is created, goes into the 
                         value of X4 
                         (2)
set_variable X5          W is a non-root freshvar created in X5
                         (3)
put_structure f/1,A3     f/1 functor goes into A3
set_value X5             New (empty) cell is created, goes into the 
                         value of X5 
                         (4)
call p/3                 Go!
```

At position (1), so far, so good. `X4` and `X5` seem to implicitly be the first and second arguments of the `h/2` in A2 (is that right?)

```
X4 ----+---> [unbound REF] = Z (variable appearing at root)
       |
A1 ----+

A2 --------> [h/2] = h(X4,X5)
```

At (2)

```
X4 ----+---> [] = Z (variable appearing at root)
       |
A1 ----+

A2 --------> [h/2] = h(X4,X5)
```

At (3)

```
X4 ----+---> [] = Z (variable appearing at root)
       |
A1 ----+

A2 --------> [h/2] = h(X4,X5)

X5 --------> [myself REF] (variable not appearing at root)
```

At (4)

```
X4 ----+---> [] = Z (variable appearing at root)
       |
A1 ----+

A2 --------> [h/2] = h(X4,X5)

A3 --------> [f/1] = f(X5)

X5 --------> [] = W
```